# Why does $aN=bN \Rightarrow a^{-1}b \in N$?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

If $N \triangleleft G$ and $a,b \in G$ then why does $aN=bN$ imply $a^{-1}b \in N$?

I don't find it too obvious, sadly, since $N=a^{-1}bN$ by rearrangment, and this tells me that $a^{-1}b$ is the identity? Is that why it must be in $N$? That's the only reason I can think of but not sure whether or not it's true.

Is there a more rigorous reasoning behind it?

Comment: This is not related to the subgroup being normal. Do you know that cosets are either equal or have empty intersection?

Comment: $N=a^{-1}bN$ doesn't tell you $a^{-1}b$ is an identity. But since clearly $a^{-1}b\in a^{-1}bN$, we must also have $a^{-1}b\in N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$aN=bN$ tells you that every element on the right hand side is also an element on the left hand side (and vice versa). As $1\in N$, one particular element on the right is $b\cdot 1=b$. We conclude $b\in aN$, i.e., there exists $n\in N$ such that $b=an$. But then $a^{-1}b=n\in N$.